# how to integrate hybrid app into ios native app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sup, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a requirement like integrate hybrid app into ios application? Is it possible or not? Currently iOS application accessing SUP server as middileware and downloading the hibrid app. Now i want to change as look and feel like native. How to custamize(integrate) the both codes.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: an app can be web based, native, or hybrid, but being at the same time hybrid and native is a nonsense. Either you change it to a real native one, either you customize it to look like a native one.

Comment: okay, if i want to custmize it like native what needs to do?

Comment: yes i did the customization, how to call or initiate the hybrid app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution for this issue. Just follow the below links:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01853.0222/doc/html/vhu1333388244905.html

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01853.0222/doc/html/vhu1333388244905.html

Here as a developer we have to take bit care of 2 things. In these steps chance to do mistake:

1) Adding hybrid app folder: While adding the hybrid app folder should select second option.[image: While adding the hybrid app folder should select second option.]

2) Resource path for hybrid app:

suppose to give resource path like this in iOS.

NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HybridAppFolderName"];

But here just give to : NSString *path = @"HybridAppFolderName";

I hope this will help to you..